# XOR neural network, the losses don't go down

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron, mxnet

I'm using Mxnet to train a XOR neural network, but the losses don't go down, they are always above 0.5.

Below is my code in Mxnet 1.1.0; Python 3.6; OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

I tried 2 loss functions - squared loss and softmax loss, both didn't work.

```
from mxnet import ndarray as nd
from mxnet import autograd
from mxnet import gluon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = nd.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
y = nd.array([0,1,1,0])
batch_size = 1
dataset = gluon.data.ArrayDataset(X, y)
data_iter = gluon.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True)

plt.scatter(X[:, 1].asnumpy(),y.asnumpy())
plt.show()

net = gluon.nn.Sequential()
with net.name_scope():
    net.add(gluon.nn.Dense(2, activation="tanh"))
    net.add(gluon.nn.Dense(1, activation="tanh"))
net.initialize()

softmax_cross_entropy = gluon.loss.SigmoidBCELoss()#SigmoidBinaryCrossEntropyLoss()
square_loss = gluon.loss.L2Loss()
trainer = gluon.Trainer(net.collect_params(), 'sgd', {'learning_rate': 0.3})

train_losses = []

for epoch in range(100):
    train_loss = 0
    for data, label in data_iter:
        with autograd.record():
            output = net(data)
            loss = square_loss(output, label)
        loss.backward()
        trainer.step(batch_size)

        train_loss += nd.mean(loss).asscalar()
    train_losses.append(train_loss)

plt.plot(train_losses)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the learning rate?

Comment: @Sahil Yes, from 0.01 to 0.5, the resulted losses are always above 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this question figured out in somewhere else, so I'm going to post the answer here.

Basically, the issue in my original code was multi-dimensional.

1. Weight initialization. Notice that I used default initialization

> net.initialize()

which actually does

> net.initialize(initializer.Uniform(scale=0.07))

Apparently these initial weights were too small, and the network could never jump out of them. So the fix is

> net.initialize(mx.init.Uniform(1))

After doing this, the network could converge using `sigmoid/tanh` as the **activation**, and using `L2Loss` as the **loss function**. And it worked with `sigmoid` and `SigmoidBCELoss`. However, it still didn't work with `tanh` and `SigmoidBCELoss`, which can be fixed by the second item below.

2. `SigmoidBCELoss` has to be used in these 2 scenarios in the output layer.

   2.1. **Linear activation** and `SigmoidBCELoss(from_sigmoid=False)`;

   2.2. **Non-linear activation** and `SigmoidBCELoss(from_sigmoid=True)`, in which the output of the non-linear function falls into (0, 1).

In my original code, when I used `SigmoidBCELoss`, I was using either all `sigmoid`, or all `tanh`. So just need to change the activation in the output layer from `tanh` to `sigmoid`, and the network could converge. I can still have `tanh` in the hidden layers.

Hope this helps!